# innerHTML not updating properly

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml

I'm trying to build some basic HTML form validation in Javascript.  My form is held in a table and I've got an extra column to the right of each input with an ID of "ErrorX", which is initially populated with some text to show it's a required field.

```
<FORM NAME="ContactForm" METHOD=POST ACTION='Order3.php' onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<TABLE>
 <TR>
  <TD ALIGN=LEFT>Your name:</TD>
  <TD ALIGN=RIGHT><INPUT TYPE=TEXT ID="Field1" NAME="Field1"></TD>
  <TD ALIGN=LEFT ID="Error1">Required</TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
<input type=submit value='Confirm ->'></FORM>
```

When the submit button is pressed, I've got the code validates the fields and attempts to change the right-most column text.  The line of code that does this is:

```
document.getElementById("Error1").innerHTML = "ERROR";
```

The code executes and detects the error correctly, and the existing wording is removed, but the new text does not appear.  If I query the value of document.getElementById("Error1").innerHTML, I get the correct text, but it's not appearing on the screen.

I'm using Safari v5.1.2 and it works with basic examples I've copied from the web, so I think it's my code rather than the browser.

Comment: Could it be that the form gets posted, and therefor reloads so you don't see that it works? Do you return false in validate?

Comment: Might want to fix your HTML, ton of mistakes (no doulble quotes, using `->` in the submit button instead of the web safe equiv), did you use frontpage by chance?

Comment: IMHO you should learn the basics of HTML before JavaScript. Your sample HTML looks like HTML 4.0 which should be replaced by XHTML 1.x or HTML 5. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/ for more help.

Comment: @Jakub: Nothing wrong with excluding double quotes in this case.

Comment: More info is needed. I tested the code on three browsers including Windows version of Safari 5.1.2, no problem, when validateForm() is defined simply as making the assignment and returning false. The problem is apparently somewhere else than in the parts described so far.

Comment: @naveen normaly I would refer the german site selfhtml.org which is my main reference since years. I saw often good hints on w3schools so I see no problem with linking their page.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I did return false in the validate function - but you did get me wondering...

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` works for sure in safari. See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/zxMKM/

The obvious reason is that your html markup is invalid and the browser does its own error recovery and producing its own DOM in the process.
So please validate your html http://validator.w3.org/

Also please note that `td.innerHTML` is read only for IE8.
So, its more cross platform friendly to use `td.innerText`

Comment: *"The obvious reason is that your html markup is invalid"* What invalid markup are you talking about that would cause this behavior?

Comment: @am not i am: please read the question carefully. op has posted only part of his markup. i am pretty sure that the html will have an invalid markup inside that. and if you see this markup as valid. then its another reason why html5 emerged. xhtml is too forgiving.

Comment: XHTML is **less** forgiving. You being *"pretty sure"* that there's *other* invalid markup on the page is irrelevant. The **only** HTML4/5 validation issue here is that the submit `<input>` should be nested in another element. The cause of this issue is not validation.

Comment: :) tell me any other scenario where innerhtml won't work for a td in safari? also i was not mentioning about case sensitivity when i was mentioning the forgiving not for case-sensitivity. i take my forgiving comment back

Comment: The question states *"...the existing wording is removed..."*. If the issue was such bad HTML that the `Error1` element isn't created, then the existing wording wouldn't be removed at all. Everyone is talking about invalid HTML in the question, when there's only one minor validation issue.

Comment: please see *".....My form is held in a table and I've got an extra column to the right of each input with an ID of "ErrorX", which is initially populated with some text to show it's a required field....."*
which essentially means that we have lots more of data we have not seen

Comment: Of course. That doesn't automatically mean it is invalid markup, or if it is, it doesn't mean it is the cause of the issue. Please read my first comment. Your claim is that the *"obvious"* reason is that there's invalid markup. There is only one very minor validation issue here, and so no real reason to believe that HTML validation is the reason.

Comment: i guess we are wasting much of your time as the clarifications sought are not answered yet

Comment: Thanks for all the comments people.  I think you're right about the HTML - It's being generated by PHP (and I'm a programmer, but not an HTML expert) so there's a good chance that something's going wrong there - I simplified the output to keep the question succinct.  I'm happy to attach the full page if people want to see it - it's just quite a lot of output!  I know the update is taking place (I can use an alert to show me the current value, and the fact that the old text disappears is a good sign), but the revised content does not appear.  I'm off to check my HTML using the tools mentioned..

Comment: Solved! Found a hangover bit of Javascript from a previous attempt that was corrupting the HTML.  Really appreciate all your support.  Many thanks.

Comment: happy to help and please use innerText if you want this working at IE

Comment: Have updated to innerText now as it will need to work in IE too.  Thanks!

Comment: In reality, innerText works on fewer browsers than innerHTML; innerText is an IE invention, though now rather widely supported by other browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on iPAD safari,  it is not updating div value properly.
I have gone through lot of posts and tried out lot of options, but what works for me is **text().**

Answer (score -2):

```
<td align="left"><div id="Error1">Required</div></td>
```

Comment: align=".." is depricted now, you should use CSS to align the text

Comment: this -1 is a bit harsh. nesting the error inside an element sort of nullifies the invalid markup effect. @craig123!: a `label` instead of `div` would have been more apt.